# Any solutions to capture data within a website automatically?

Tags: database, ajax, screen-scraping

I want to write an application to capture data from a website, and the website are using ajax to retrieve data from server.
Is there any solutions that I can get those data conveniently and store into my own database ? As the data in that website is dynamic, historical data will disappear, and I want to keep track them.

Please suggest any solutions, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium RC can do this with a little bit of work.\

http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Actually I don't want to test the website, I need some libraries to help me capture data from website.

Comment: Selenium can do this.  Once you request a page you can parse the response to get the information you need and store it in the database.  It doesn't have to used as part of testing.

Answer (score 0):

You may try IRobotSoft Web Scraper.   Check demos here http://irobotsoft.com/help/ to see if it is what you want.